# cannot set 'name' of undefined when throwing exception

Tags: node.js, thrift

I was just trying Apache Thrift in nodejs before using it in my upcoming project wherein I ran into this error.

Here is my `demo.thrift` file

```
namespace js demo

typedef i32 int

enum Operation {
  ADD = 1,
  SUBTRACT = 2,
  MULTIPLY = 3,
  DIVIDE = 4
}

struct Work {
  1: int num1 = 0,
  2: int num2,
  3: Operation op,
  4: optional string comment
}

exception InvalidOperation {
  1: int message,
  2: string trace
}

service Calculator {

  void ping()

  double calculate(1: int logid, 2: Work w) throws (1: InvalidOperation oops),

  oneway void zip()
}
```

Here is a part of the `server.js`

I use switch case to determine operation in `server.js`

```
// inside thrift.createServer
calculate: (logid, work, result) => {
let answer = null, oops = null;
switch(work.op) {
// Code related to Operation.ADD, Operation.SUBTRACT ...
    default: {
      console.log("ERROR!");
      oops = InvalidOperation();
      oops.message = work.op;
      oops.trace = "Unknown Operation";
   }
}
   result(oops, answer);
}
```

When the `client.js` calls server with `calculate(12345, { num1:1, num2:2, op: 10 })`

Instead of returning an error it throws 
`TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined in demo_types.js:122`

The part related to InvalidOperation in `demo_types.js` is

```
// Work related code
var InvalidOperation = module.exports.InvalidOperation = function(args) {
  Thrift.TException.call(this, "InvalidOperation");
  this.name = "InvalidOperation"; // points to here
  this.message = null;
  this.trace = null;
  if (args) {
    if (args.message !== undefined && args.message !== null) {
      this.message = args.message;
    }
    if (args.trace !== undefined && args.trace !== null) {
      this.trace = args.trace;
    }
  }
};
Thrift.inherits(InvalidOperation, Thrift.TException);
InvalidOperation.prototype.name = 'InvalidOperation';
// InvalidOperation.read & .write
```

Any idea why the error is being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I realised why this error is being thrown. It is a plain old Javascript mistake.

`oops = new InvalidOperation();`

That's it.

Comment: (1) you can accept youir own answer as answer. (2) is that a bug in your code or is it Thrift  code (generated or library)?

Comment: This was definitely a "me" bug. This answer saved me time facepalming.